# MailgunでDNSの設定が成功しているのにDisableになる

Tags: mail

Mastodonの認証メール用にMailgunを設定しています。

DNSサーバーはFreeDNSで、Mailgunの「Domain Verification & DNS」に表示されている通りレコードを設定し、Checkボタンを押すとちゃんと各レコードにチェックマークがつきます。

しかし、一番上のStateはDisableのままです。

MailgunのFAQサイトも読んでみたのですが、いまいち理解できなくて困っています。

どうすればうまくいくでしょうか

Answer (score 0):

https://mailgun.com/app/account/settings
クレジットカードの登録は完了しているでしょうか。

Comment: クレジットカードはなしでは動きませんか？

Comment: https://mailgun.com/app/account/authorized
Authorized Recipients に指定したメールアドレス宛てだけであればクレジットカード登録なしでも大丈夫でしたが、不特定多数となると登録自体は必要なようですね。
クレジットカードを登録しても、月間1万通を超えなければ無料で利用できますよ。